# Easier way to align textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm following a tutorial online. In the tutorial when he unwraps the object (using Smart UV Project), it seems to unwrap differently to how mine did

However I've moved things around in the UV/Image Editor to match how his unwrapped, however cannot seem to manually align things up properly - is there an easier way to do this? You can see from the image below that each side has not lined up exactly

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: I would suggest : In Edit mode select all of your cube and UV unwrap again. When the Smart UV Project menu pops up make sure that the Island Margin value is set to 0.00. This should then UV unwrap as in the Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isB0QIyvJcU  0:25sec.

Comment: Thank you, yes that was the tutorial. Unfortunately this didn't fix the issue as it did the same as before, although I have managed to fix it now